# Ajax to send form to server, fails at serialize?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

It seems like i cant get to serialize my form. I do get the first alert with lol, but not the second alert with pdata. Does anyone see whats wrong? Im trying to use ajax to send the data in the form. Down below is the script and the html code.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        function dologin(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            alert("lol");
            var pdata = $('#form').serialize();
            alert(pdata);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: pdata,
                url: 'LINK',
                success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    alert("YAY");
                },
                error: function() {
                    //console.log(data);
                    alert("NAY");
                } 
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Logg inn</h1>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="dologin()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Epost</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login" value="" placeholder="Epost">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="password">Passord</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" placeholder="Passord">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me">
        Husk meg
        </label>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Logg inn</button>
    </form>

    <div class="login-help">
      <p>Glemt passordet? <a href="index.html">Trykk her for å endre det</a>.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While it looks like your implementation looks correct, I believe you want to use [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but have you actually included jQuery? If not it would certainly not get past the first use of $

Comment: Did... did you include jQuery? ..edit: ninja'd!

Comment: Yes I did, sorry its not included in the sample here, my bad.

Comment: Since you're never reaching the second alert, there must be an error.  **Look at your JavaScript console... what does it say?**

Comment: @user3443163: The problem with your code is you are accessing **event** argument wheres there is no parameter passed to the **dologin** function. Look into my answer

Comment: Ah sorry guys, it was the jQuery. It couldn't take it directly from google, so I had to download it and put it in as a local src..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, you are accessing **event** argument wheres there is no parameter passed to the function, so its triggering an error and submitting the form as normal form submission.

If you like to keep your implementation u can modify your code like bellow:

```
function dologin() {

    alert("lol");
    var pdata = $('#form').serialize();
    alert(pdata);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: pdata,
        url: 'LINK',
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            alert("YAY");
        },
        error: function() {
            //console.log(data);
            alert("NAY");
        }
    });

   return false;
};
```

and modify this line

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="dologin()">
```

to

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return dologin()">
```

or can use the following way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            url: 'LINK',
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
                alert("YAY");
            },
            error: function() {
                //console.log(data);
                alert("NAY");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And form tag should be then:

```
<form id="form">
```